# Using the neovim lua api to automatically open a neovim `:term` and enter text

Tags: lua, neovim

Essentially when I'm debugging, I tend to open a new tab with four different terminals as such:

```
-------------
|     |     |
|     |     |
-------------
|     |     |
|     |     |
-------------
```

In one of these terminals I would first run `make` to build the thing I want to debug and then open an instance of `gdb` inside all them. Is there a way to automate this using the lua api? I took a stab at this myself and what I have (so far) that is non-functional is this:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_command('tabnew | term')
vim.api.nvim_command('startinsert')
vim.api.nvim_command('insert "make -j4"')
vim.api.nvim_command('vsplit | term')
vim.api.nvim_command('split | term')
```

As of now it doesn't get passed making the first terminal, error-ring out because it tries to enter text in a "non-modifiable" buffer, which I guess is the base state of the first terminal buffer.

Comment: To activate for example your first bash you need a or i to activate it. You can do this also with: ```:lua vim.api.nvim_command('tabnew | term') vim.api.nvim_input('a')```

Comment: Or direcly after the a or i: ```:lua vim.api.nvim_command('term') vim.api.nvim_input('i make clean && make || make\n')```